# How to implement random function where each subsequent value is less probable than the previous?

Tags: c++, random

For comparation the standard random function takes number, let's say `3`, then it means that `0`, `1` and `2` each has 33% chance to return.

I need to implement random function that takes let's say `0.5` then it means that `0` has 50% chance to return, `1` is 25%, `2` is 12.5%, and so on until infinity.

I can't use loops for example:

```
int SequencialRandom(double x)
{
    int result=0;
    while (DoubleRandom()>x) //DoubleRandom() returns randomized double that ranges from 0.0 to 1.0.
        result++;
    return result;
}
```

because when I put `0.01` in the parameter, on average it will loop 100 times, and it's performance bad. Is there good algorithm for this problem?

Comment: @user2864740 You think I can kill the first two paragraphs now?

Comment: I think they are fine. Just ensure titles capture the "heart" of the problem.

Comment: @user2864740 OK, I deleted the first one at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int GeometericRandom(double distribution)
{
    return (int)floor(ln(DoubleRandom())/ln(distribution));
}
```

No loops (The complexity is only O(1)) and the plot of the function `floor(ln(x)/ln(0.5)) 0<x<1` looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

What you're looking for is the geometric distribution, as provided by [std::geometric_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/geometric_distribution):

> Produces random non-negative integer values i, distributed according to discrete probability function:
>
> *P(i|p) = p · (1 − p)<sup>i</sup>*
>
> The value represents the number of yes/no trials (each succeeding with probability p) which are necessary to obtain a single success.

Example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <random>
int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::seed_seq seed{r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r()};
    std::mt19937 gen(seed);
 
    // same as std::negative_binomial_distribution<> d(1, 0.5);
    std::geometric_distribution<> d;
 
    std::map<int, int> hist;
    for(int n=0; n<10000; ++n) {
        ++hist[d(gen)];
    }
    for(auto p : hist) {
        std::cout << p.first <<
                ' ' << std::string(p.second/100, '*') << '\n';
    }
}
```

Distribution output:

```
0 **************************************************
1 ************************
2 ************
3 ******
4 **
5 *
6 
7 
8 
9 
10 
13
```

Comment: Ouch, doesn't it mean I need to create map for every little value? Because I don't think the value will be constant.

Comment: @KugBuBu The map here is just for storing results so that a nice histogram can be printed. Generating a value is done solely by the `d(gen)` expression.

Comment: OK I thought `std::geometric_distribution<>` is depend on some external thing for the actual distribution (It was a bit confusing to me), thanks.

Comment: I am considering accepting my own answer because it's complexity is `O(1)`, and I don't know the complexity of this method.

Comment: @KugBuBu if you're concerned about performance compare the two.